# Vectorized Rolling/Cumulative Mahalanobis Distance in R

Tags: r, mahalanobis

I'm trying to calculate a rolling mahalanobis distance without resorting to for loops and failing miserably.

Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(label = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
               date = rep(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "days", length.out = 5), 2),
               valx = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1), rnorm(5, mean = 1.5, sd = 1)),
               valy = c(rnorm(5, mean = 100, sd = 10), rnorm(5, mean = 115, sd = 10)),
               valz = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 10), rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 30)))
```

I'm trying to calculate, by group (`label`), the mahalanobis distance of `valx`, `valy`, and `valz`, but only using rows from that date (`date`) or previous. My current solution is to loop through each `label`, loop through each `date`, filter the dataset down to the matching data, calculate distance using `stats::mahalanobis`, add that distance to a list, and then `do.call` and `rbind` them outside the loop*. Clearly this isn't ideal.

I suspect that there's some way to write:

```
cum.mdist <- function(df, cols) {...}
df %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(mdist = xapply(., c(valx, valy, valz), cum.mdist)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

in a similar way to calculating a rolling unary function like so:

```
cumsd <- function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), function(k, z) sd(z[1:k]), z = x)
```

I could calculate the distance from component parts if there were no covariance (rolling variance variance is simple to calculate using a function like the above one), but I think my variables *do* have covariance, and I'm not sure how to build a rolling covariance matrix...

Does a solution to this exist outside of for loops?

---

*code for a looped solution is below:

```
library("tidyverse")
df <- data.frame(label = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
                 date = rep(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "days", length.out = 5), 2),
                 valx = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1), rnorm(5, mean = 1.5, sd = 1)),
                 valy = c(rnorm(5, mean = 100, sd = 10), rnorm(5, mean = 115, sd = 10)),
                 valz = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 10), rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 30)))
mdist.list <- vector(length = nrow(df), mode = "list")
counter <- 1

for(l in seq_along(unique(df$label))){
  label_data <- df %>%
    filter(label == unique(df$label)[l])

  for(d in seq_along(unique(label_data$date))){
    label_date_data <- label_data %>%
      filter(date <= unique(label_data$date)[d])

    if(nrow(label_date_data) > 3){
      label_date_data$mdist <- mahalanobis(label_date_data %>% select(contains("val")),
                                           colMeans(label_date_data %>% select(contains("val"))),
                                           cov(label_date_data %>% select(contains("val"))))
    } else{
      label_date_data$mdist <- NA
    }

    mdist.list[[counter]] <- filter(label_date_data, 
                                    date == unique(label_data$date)[d])

    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}

mdist.df <- do.call(rbind, mdist.list)
```

Comment: can you show an example of how you would call the mahalanobis function with your df dataset?

Comment: I added the code I'm using for a looped solution to the question, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your requirements or desired output correctly, here is something using `data.table` to get you started:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, mdist := 
    .SD[, transpose(lapply(1L:.N, function(n) {
        ma <- .SD[1L:n]
        ans <- tryCatch(mahalanobis(ma, colMeans(ma), var(ma)), error=function(e) NA)
        ans[length(ans)]            
    })), by=.(label), .SDcols=valx:valz]$V1]
```

output:

```
    label       date         valx       valy        valz     mdist
 1:     A 2018-01-01  1.262954285   7.635935  -2.2426789        NA
 2:     A 2018-01-02 -0.326233361  -7.990092   3.7739565        NA
 3:     A 2018-01-03  1.329799263 -11.476570   1.3333636        NA
 4:     A 2018-01-04  1.272429321  -2.894616   8.0418951 2.2500000
 5:     A 2018-01-05  0.414641434  -2.992151  -0.5710677 0.7260652
 6:     B 2018-01-01 -1.539950042  -4.115108  15.1082392        NA
 7:     B 2018-01-02 -0.928567035   2.522234  32.5730809        NA
 8:     B 2018-01-03 -0.294720447  -8.919211 -20.7286152        NA
 9:     B 2018-01-04 -0.005767173   4.356833 -38.5379806 2.2500000
10:     B 2018-01-05  2.404653389 -12.375384   1.4017852 3.0800360
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
df <- data.frame(label = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
    date = rep(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "days", length.out = 5), 2),
    valx = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1), rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1)),
    valy = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 10), rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 10)),
    valz = c(rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 10), rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 30)))
```

I will delete this post if you are looking only for a `tidyverse` solution.

Comment: While I would prefer a `tidyverse` solution, if this massively reduces my runtime I think I can figure out how to apply it to my problem. Is there an issue with leaving this solution if I don't accept it as solved?